# Is there any way to disable or increase port name length in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create a deployment on Kubernetes but getting this error;

`http.paths[0].backend.service.port.name: Invalid value: \"<deployment-name>-service\": must be no more than 15 characters"`

I don't have any chance to interfere to the port name directly, but deployment name. I have to pass long deployment name, but it's not possible right now. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: See [Issue #50619](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50619): The service name can not be longer than 15 characters according to [RFC 6335](https://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=6335).

Answer (score 3):

You can not disable or increase port name length in kubernetes . As @Sascha Doerdelmann mentioned, it's a k8s limitation that port names are 15 characters.

According to [RFC 6335](https://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=6335).

Valid service names are hereby normatively defined as follows:

1. MUST be at least 1 character and no more than **15 characters** long.
2. MUST contain only US-ASCII [ANSI.X3.4-1986] letters 'A' - 'Z' and
   'a' - 'z', digits '0' - '9', and hyphens ('-', ASCII 0x2D or
   decimal 45).
3. MUST contain at least one letter ('A' - 'Z' or 'a' - 'z').
4. MUST NOT begin or end with a hyphen.
5. hyphens MUST NOT be adjacent to other hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

you can truncate the value and set it to the limit that is allowed

```
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . | trunc 7 }}-service
```

[helm-fuction-trunc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#trunc)